# Logging Powershell output in a specific format

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to output the following to a log file ($log) in the following format:

```
www.mydomain1.com : <the dig output stuff>
www.mydomain2.com : <the dig output stuff>
etc..
```

However when I try the script below, I'm only getting the following format (missing the write-output / domain name):

```
<the dig output stuff>
```

How can I get these two items to print to the the same line?

```
 ForEach    ($domain in $domains) {
    $cmd = "c:\Tools\dig\dig.exe ``@8.8.8.8 $domain +short +nssearch"
    Write-Output $domain :  >> $log
    Invoke-Expression $cmd >> $log
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested but should just be able to capture the results of the command in a variable and build the output string with the format operator. We also use `Add-Content` for a cleaner appearing code solution. Also no need for `Invoke-Expression` but might need to change the string a bit.

```
ForEach    ($domain in $domains) {
    $results = & "c:\Tools\dig\dig.exe" "@8.8.8.8 $domain +short +nssearch"
    ('{0} : {1}' -f $domain,$results) | Add-Content $log
}
```

Problem the way you had it is you should have had your expected data on two lines which is not what you wanted. I think the reason you didn't even see that was that your output line should have been a single string  `Write-Output "$domain :"  >> $log`.

Comment: Thank you - I was able to get it to work as I needed based on your example.  I appreciate it!